# Registering Handlebars string comparison helper in Ember.js not working

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to implement a string comparison helper in my ember app and I keep getting this error :

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named `if_eq` could not be found

I can't believe it's that complicated to compare 2 strings together, it should be a basic but seems like it's not the case. So where am I wrong? Should I use something else to compare the strings?

Template :

```
{{#if_eq selectedConv.status 'opened'}}
  <button><span class="close">Close</span></button>
{{else}}
  <button><span class="close">Open</span></button>
{{/if_eq}}
```

Helper (directly in js file)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
if(a == b) // Or === depending on your needs
    return opts.fn(this);
else
    return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

Comment: I succesfully did the comparison by registering and Ember.handlebars helper. But it doesn't evaluate the value of selectedConv.status and just formats it into a string, any ideas?

Comment: Being a noob as usual. Just added a true/false parameter in controller, changing it as depending on state of conversation. Evaluated this param in handlebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a better idea to have a computed property on the `selectedConv` object like `isOpened`. This is quite easy to do and a re-usable option if needed elsewhere in your app. Just add this additional code to the definition of `selectedConv`:

```
isOpened: Ember.computed('status', function () {
  return Ember.get(this, 'status') === 'opened';
})
```

This will allow you to simplify your template to this:

```
{{#if selectedConv.isOpened}}
  <button><span class="close">Close</span></button>
{{else}}
  <button><span class="close">Open</span></button>
{{/if}}
```

More information about computed properties to help you get started can be found in the [Ember Guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/object-model/computed-properties/).

If you insist on using conditional helpers, you are probably better off using a library that is already readily available like [Ember Truth Helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers).